# Can't upgrade m2e with STS 3.7

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I'm running Spring Tool Suite 3.70 RELEASE (build ID 201506290652).

It's telling me that there are upgrades available for a number of components but when I try to do the upgrade I get a complaint that the repositories can not be located. Also, when I start it, I get an error that automatic updates can't be performed (or something to that effect) with the same details I'm posting below.

Is there a way to change the repository location, or is this a more significant issue?

Thanks...

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile,     phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.branding.ui,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.commons.core,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.commons.ui,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.core,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.ui,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.monitor.core,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.monitor,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.monitor.ui,3.0.8.v20130328
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.extensionbundle,1.2.0.v20100503
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.roo.wrapping.protobuf-java-lite,2.3.0.0001
```

Comment: not exactly sure what is going on, but we published a new STS version a few minutes ago (including updated m2e), so you might want to jump to that version right away. Would be interesting to know whether an automatic update works for you (with the new version) or if the problem persists. If so, you could start with a fresh STS 3.7.1 install or we would need more details for analyzing the problem (list of installed features and list of configured update sites).

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that today and post back.

Comment: Well I finally tried to upgrade STS itself, but got the same error. I'll update my original question to post my configuration details.

Comment: Okay, I was going to post my configuration, taken from STS, but its huge. This is all running on a Macbook with OS X Yosemite. Where would I find the list of configured update sites?

Comment: The list of configured update sites is in the Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Update Sites.

Comment: Maybe wiping out the p2 repo caches helps as well. Shutdown STS, delete the p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache directory and restart STS. Also sometimes removing all the update sites and add them back after a restart helps, too.

Comment: I deleted that directory as you suggested, but it made no difference. I looked at my update sites as you described, and there are a bunch of them. Frankly, I don't know what I should have. The error presented is: 'Updating Software' has encountered a problem. An error occurred while collecting items to be installed. I'll post the "details" int he next comment.

Comment: This is not complete but it goes on like this: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.branding,1.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.core,1.4.0.v201310142259
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jpt.common.eclipselink.branding,1.3.100.v201310142259

Comment: did you try to remove all the update sites and add them back again? It certainly looks like an issue with stale cache p2 data somewhere...

Comment: and as a last resort you could install a fresh STS 3.7.1 distribution and go from there. If you have third-party plugins installed and hate to re-install all of them manually, you could try to automate that using a script like this: https://gist.github.com/martinlippert/5155155